# In a deployment diagram, when should I underline the name of the Deployment or put a colon beforehand?

Tags: design, uml, deployment

Per the [UML 2.5.1 specification](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1):

> DeployedTargets are shown as a perspective view of cube labeled with the name of the DeployedTarget shown prepended by a colon. System elements deployed on a DeployedTarget, and Deployments that connect them, may be drawn inside the perspective cube. Alternately, deployed system elements can be shown as a textual list of element names.

Two example figures from the UML 2.5.1 specification:

[image: Example UML Specification 2017]

I figured that without the colon or underline, the Deployment is an instance, but how should we differentiate between them? For example, in a Google Chrome box, should the deployment diagram be underlined?

Comment: link to the thing you are taking the diagrams from?

Comment: @Ewan I checked - it's the UML specification. See my edits. They appear in the 2.5.1 version, which is the current version. I didn't check older versions.

Answer (score 1):

Jeeze they make this complicated.

I think the first example (19.14) is underlined because it's an "InstanceSpecification" of an AppServer.

> An InstanceSpecification is depicted using similar notation to its
> classifiers, but in place of the Classifier name appears an underlined
> concatenation of the instance name (if any), a colon (‘:’) and the
> Classifier name or names

The Second (19.15) is just a diagram of the communication, which doesn't relate to a specific instance. So its not underlined.

I'm not sure this makes a whole load of sense, if we look at fig 19.3 for example. Here we have a "Deployment" or "DeploymentTarget"? which seems to show an almost identical thing, but with an underline and colon.

[image: fig 19.3]

I think the intended use of the underline is to represent a specific instance of a thing rather than the specification of a thing. If we look at the class and other examples we have `:Person` and `D̲o̲n̲ ̲:̲ ̲P̲e̲r̲s̲o̲n̲`

When it comes to InstanceSpecifications, it seems odd that they are underlined as they can represent non-existing instances. so I would expect diagrams to have `:AppServer` or `a̲p̲p̲S̲e̲r̲v̲e̲r̲1̲:̲A̲p̲p̲S̲e̲r̲v̲e̲r̲`. But there seems to be confusion in the specification as to whether InstanceSpecifications are specifications, or instances